# Need to get focus in and focus out events for SecureField SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I know there is a focus handler in TextField - onEditingChanged. But I am using a SecureField along with the TextField (used in a context of password hide and show) i need to get the focus in and focus out events of both SecureField and TextField for performing an animation. I can achieve this using onEditingChanged for TextField but how about SecureField?

Note : I am working on IOS app dev. So 'focusable' cannot be used

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

SecureField do not have `onEditingChanged` and this is a small little trick that you can do is to continue using Textfield but change the `foregroundColor` to `clear` so that it is not visible to the user. In this way, you can do the thing you want.

```
ZStack {
     SecureField("", text: $text)
          .font(.system(size: fontSize))
                
     TextField("", text: $text, onEditingChanged: { focused in
          .....
     })
       .foregroundColor(.clear)
       .disableAutocorrection(disableAutocorrection)
       .font(.system(size: fontSize))
            
}
```